# Why does a SELECT query (Sch-S) get blocked due to an existing Sch-S lock held by index reorganize command?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, statistics, blocking, index-maintenance

SELECT query requires a SCH-S lock. This can be shared with other read queries.

UPDATE query requires a SCH-M lock. This cannot be shared with other read/update queries.

Link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5880/why-is-index-reorganize-and-update-statistics-causing-sql-server-blocking/

The example shows an index reorg (Sch-S) lock blocks the statistics update's Sch-M lock. But why does it also block the subsequent Sch-S lock requested by the SELECT query? Aren't Sch-S locks shared?

Comment: "UPDATE query requires a SCH-M lock" do you mean "UPDATE STATISTICS requires a SCH-M lock"? As explained in the article, the `Sch-M` wait itself is what's blocking the `Sch-S` for the `SELECT`, this in turn is blocked by the `Sch-S` of the `ALTER INDEX`. So it's a chain of blocking, they are not all waiting on the original `Sch-S` directly

Comment: In general the low priority wait options are to prevent this sort of blocking chain - but doesn't look like `UPDATE STATISTICS` has that  as an option

Comment: @Charlieface - The initial Sch-S lock is blocking the Sch-M lock. But since the Sch-S is a shared lock then why is the SELECT query's Sch-S blocked? Aren't Sch-S shared locks?

Comment: It can't jump the queue ahead of the `Sch-M` lock. Otherwise the `Sch-M` could be permanently starved by a steady stream of `Sch-S` locks. This is what the  low priority wait options allow you to specify a preference for

Comment: Do NOLOCK queries also have to wait in the queue?

Comment: No it can't jump the queue as mentioned. Each one waits for the one before it. Yes, even `NOLOCK` take out schema locks, that would be exactly the same. It's only read-only table/page/row locks that it doesn't take (and you shouldn't use `NOLOCK` anyway)

Comment: Brilliant article on this topic: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/running-sap-applications-on-the/new-functionality-in-sql-server-2014-8211-part-3-8211-low/ba-p/367685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Charlieface points out, it's a sequential chain of blocking that's occuring. `SCH-S` and `SCH-M` are incompatible lock types with each other. You can use the following lock compatibility matrix from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017#lock_compatibility) to see what's compatible:

[image: Lock Compatibility Matrix]

In the example you provided from MS SQL Tips, there is an `ALTER INDEX` `SCH-S` locking query that's blocking an `UPDATE STATISTICS` query that uses an `SCH-M` lock. And then that `UPDATE STATISTICS` query is blocking a third query (a `SELECT`) that uses an `SCH-S` lock. So `SCH-S` blocks `SCH-M` blocks `SCH-S` is the chain of blocking here, because they're incompatible lock types in both directions.

Comment: At the moment when the Sch-S is blocking the Sch-M, what prevents the SELECT 's Sch-S ? Aren't Sch-S shared?

Comment: The `SCH-M` is blocking the SELECT's `SCH-S`. (As I mentioned in the answer it's a chain of blocking.)